# How to modify a gitlab CI service, need to increase the number of available postgres connections?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am using postgres:12-alpine service, and I need to increase the maximum number of available postgres connections. Generally in order to do that I would need to modify postgres.conf file.

Is there a way for me to access and edit a config file on that system that provides postgres:12-alpine service? Or perhaps some other way to exit max_connections setting of postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to see if the `postgres:12-alpine` Docker image supports configuring the max connections via an environment variable. If so, you can set those variables in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. See [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#passing-environment-variables-to-services) or below for an example of environment variables used by a service:

```yaml
# The following variables are automatically passed down to the Postgres container
# as well as the Ruby container and available within each.
variables:
  HTTPS_PROXY: "https://10.1.1.1:8090"
  HTTP_PROXY: "https://10.1.1.1:8090"
  POSTGRES_DB: "my_custom_db"
  POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "example"
  PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
  POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "--encoding=UTF8 --data-checksums"

services:
  - name: postgres:11.7
    alias: db
    entrypoint: ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    command: ["postgres"]

image:
  name: ruby:2.6
  entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]

before_script:
  - bundle install

test:
  script:
    - bundle exec rake spec
```

These variables (as well as the service and image) are defined at the pipeline level ("default") rather than the job level, so they apply to every job in the pipeline, but the syntax is the same to add them to a single job:

```
test:
  image: ruby:2.6
  services:
    - postgres:11.7
  script:
    - bundle exec rake spec
```

You can read about settings variables in each of the applicable places here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#gitlab-ciyml-defined-variables

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve this by using the "command" keyword inside the service:

```
services:
  - name: postgres:12-alpine
    alias: postgres
    command:
      - “postgres”
      - “-c”
      - “max_connections=1000”
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#self-managed-gitlab-uses-two-database-connections) (May 2023) changes the setup:

> ### Self-managed GitLab uses two database connections
>
> Starting with 16.0, self-managed installations of GitLab will have two database connections by default, instead of one.
>
> This change makes self-managed versions of GitLab behave similarly to GitLab.com, and is a step towards enabling a [separate database for CI features](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7509) for self-managed versions of GitLab.
>
> This change applies to installation methods with Omnibus GitLab, GitLab Helm chart, GitLab Operator, GitLab Docker images, and installation from source.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html#configuring-multiple-database-connections) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/9627).

So, for GitLab 16.0 and later:

- PostgreSQL version 12 is no longer supported, and the binaries have been removed. To proceed, administrators must ensure the installation is using [PostgreSQL 13](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html#upgrade-packaged-postgresql-server).
- In GitLab 16.0, GitLab defaults to using two database connections that point to the same PostgreSQL database.
  Prior to upgrading to GitLab 16.0, you can check that PostgreSQL `max_connections` is high enough (using more than 50% of the available max connections).
  You can verify this by running the following Rake task:

  ```
  sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:db:decomposition:connection_status
  ```

  If the task indicates that max_connections is high enough, then you can proceed with the upgrade.